# count if multiple conditions in several arrays

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, google-docs

I have a result list. I want to count how many wins one team has won.
This means that I want to count how many times (i.e) Mashed appears, if the corresponding result is higher than the opposite teams. So Mashed would be at least 1 `if B2:B4 > C2:C4`.

Is this something that could be done?

```
enter code here
<pre>     A          B         C          D</pre>
<pre>1    Mashed     1    -    3          Fury</pre>
<pre>2    Fury       3    -    2          Gervado</pre>
<pre>3    Mashed     2    -    1          Gervado</pre>
<pre>4    Mashed     2    -    2          Fury</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can a response based with filter counta join transpose be a solution?
result is in column H & I : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao02g19G1-G-dGVPcUNyY0hDSTNLN1ZwSWFXZnVPaWc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Because specific to a single team and considers wins only may not be the best solution, but seems to meet the stated requirement:

```
=sumproduct(A:A="Mashed",B:B>C:C)
```